# How do I use for_each on a hardcoded list of objects

Tags: terraform

I have this terraform file, and it results in an error:

```
# products-index/main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    algolia = {
      source  = "k-yomo/algolia"
      version = "0.2.1"
    }
  }
}

resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
  for_each = {
    (var.index_name) = {
      ranking = [
        "typo",
        "geo",
        "words",
        "filters",
        "proximity",
        "attribute",
        "exact",
        "custom"
      ],
      custom_ranking = [
        "asc(has_ranking_malus)",
        "desc(score_a)",
        "asc(price)",
        "desc(has_free_delivery)",
        "desc(rating)",
        "desc(rating_count)"
      ],
      replicas = [
        "${var.index_name}_abtest_candidate",
        "${var.index_name}_price_asc",
        "${var.index_name}_price_desc"
      ]
    },
    "${var.index_name}_abtest_candidate" = {
      replicas = [],
      ranking = [
        "typo",
        "geo",
        "words",
        "filters",
        "proximity",
        "attribute",
        "exact",
        "custom"
      ],
      custom_ranking = [
        "asc(has_ranking_malus)",
        "desc(score_b)",
        "asc(price)",
        "desc(has_free_delivery)",
        "desc(rating)",
        "desc(rating_count)"
      ],
    },
    "${var.index_name}_price_desc" = {
      replicas = [],
      ranking = [
        "desc(price)",
        "typo",
        "geo",
        "words",
        "filters",
        "proximity",
        "attribute",
        "exact",
        "custom"
      ],
      custom_ranking = [
        "desc(has_ranking_malus)",
        "desc(score)",
        "asc(price)",
        "desc(has_free_delivery)",
        "desc(rating)",
        "desc(rating_count)"
      ],
    },
    "${var.index_name}_price_asc" = {
      replicas = [],
      ranking = [
        "asc(price)",
        "typo",
        "geo",
        "words",
        "filters",
        "proximity",
        "attribute",
        "exact",
        "custom"
      ],
      custom_ranking = [
        "desc(has_ranking_malus)",
        "desc(score)",
        "asc(price)",
        "desc(has_free_delivery)",
        "desc(rating)",
        "desc(rating_count)"
      ],
    }
  }

  name = each.key

  typos_config {
    min_word_size_for_1_typo      = 4
    min_word_size_for_2_typos     = 8
    allow_typos_on_numeric_tokens = false
    disable_typo_tolerance_on_attributes = [
      "ean",
      "me_id",
      "model_descriptions",
      "model_id",
      "mpn",
      "sku"
    ]
    typo_tolerance = "strict"
  }

  pagination_config {
    hits_per_page         = 60
    pagination_limited_to = 20000
  }

  faceting_config {
    max_values_per_facet = 1000
  }

  languages_config {
    ignore_plurals_for = [var.language]
    decompounded_attributes {
      language = var.language
      attributes = [
        "categories.last",
        "default_title",
        "model_titles"
      ]
    }
    remove_stop_words_for = [var.language]
    query_languages       = [var.language]
    custom_normalization  = var.custom_normalization
  }

  advanced_config {
    response_fields                              = ["*"]
    attribute_criteria_computed_by_min_proximity = true
    attribute_for_distinct                       = "article_id"
    distinct                                     = 1
  }

  highlight_and_snippet_config {
    attributes_to_highlight = [
      "article_id"
    ]
    highlight_pre_tag  = "<em>"
    highlight_post_tag = "</em>"
  }

  attributes_config {
    attributes_to_retrieve = ["*"]

    searchable_attributes = [
      "model_titles",
      "default_title",
      "brand_name",
      "categories.last",
      "unordered(model_descriptions)",
      "unordered(catalog_attribute)",
      "model_id",
      "me_id",
      "sku",
      "categories.l2.id",
      "categories.l3.id",
      "mpn",
      "ean"
    ]

    attributes_for_faceting = [
      "banner.alternate.categories",
      "banner.categories",
      "catalog_attribute",
      "catalog_attribute_facet",
      "categories.l1.id",
      "categories.l2",
      "categories.l2.id",
      "categories.l3",
      "categories.l3.id",
      "filterOnly(categories.l0.id)",
      "filterOnly(model_id)",
      "filterOnly(private_sale_ids)",
      "has_1day_delivery",
      "has_3x_payment",
      "has_free_delivery",
      "has_relay_delivery",
      "is_mmf",
      "prices.per_item.actual_price.with_vat.as_float",
      "prices.per_item.actual_price.without_vat.as_float",
      "prices.per_m2.actual_price.with_vat.as_float",
      "prices.per_m2.actual_price.without_vat.as_float",
      "rating",
      "searchable(brand_name)",
      "searchable(categories.last)",
      "searchable(categories.last_id)",
      "searchable(price)",
      "searchable(seller_name)"
    ]

    unretrievable_attributes = [
      "article_update_time",
      "document_update_time",
      "ean",
      "has_ranking_malus",
      "model_descriptions",
      "model_titles",
      "mpn",
      "private_sale_ids",
      "product_update_time",
      "sku"
    ]
  }

  query_strategy_config {
    remove_words_if_no_results = "allOptional"
    query_type                 = "prefixLast"
    alternatives_as_exact = [
      "ignorePlurals",
      "singleWordSynonym"
    ]
    advanced_syntax_features = [
      "exactPhrase",
      "excludeWords",
    ]
  }

  ranking_config {
    ranking = [
      "typo",
      "geo",
      "words",
      "filters",
      "proximity",
      "attribute",
      "exact",
      "custom"
    ]
    custom_ranking = [
      "asc(has_ranking_malus)",
      "desc(score_a)",
      "asc(price)",
      "desc(has_free_delivery)",
      "desc(rating)",
      "desc(rating_count)"
    ]
  }

  ranking_config {
    ranking        = each.value["ranking"]
    custom_ranking = each.value["custom_ranking"]
    replicas       = each.value["replicas"]
  }
}
```

That Terraform module is used twice in another file:

```
provider "algolia" {
  alias   = "de-b2b-nonprod"
  api_key = data.vault_generic_secret.algolia.data.DE-B2B-nonprod_api_key
  app_id  = data.vault_generic_secret.algolia.data.DE-B2B-nonprod_app_id
}

module "de-b2b-dev-index" {
  source = "..//products-index"
  providers = {
    algolia = algolia.de-b2b-nonprod
  }

  index_name = "dev_products_de"
  language   = "de"
  custom_normalization = {
    "ö" = "oe",
    "ü" = "ue",
    "ß" = "ss",
    "ä" = "ae"
  }
}

module "de-b2b-pprod-index" {
  source = "..//products-index"
  providers = {
    algolia = algolia.de-b2b-nonprod
  }

  index_name = "pprod_products_de"
  language   = "de"
  custom_normalization = {
    "ö" = "oe",
    "ü" = "ue",
    "ß" = "ss",
    "ä" = "ae"
  }
}
```

The error is repeated 8 times, and conversely, I have 8 existing resources that were previously defined without resorting to the foreach. The output looks as follows:

```
module.de-b2b-dev-index.algolia_index.price_desc_replica: Refreshing state... [id=dev_products_de_price_desc]
module.de-b2b-pprod-index.algolia_index.abtest_replica: Refreshing state... [id=pprod_products_de_abtest_candidate]
module.de-b2b-dev-index.algolia_index.abtest_replica: Refreshing state... [id=dev_products_de_abtest_candidate]
module.de-b2b-pprod-index.algolia_index.price_desc_replica: Refreshing state... [id=pprod_products_de_price_desc]
module.de-b2b-dev-index.algolia_index.price_asc_replica: Refreshing state... [id=dev_products_de_price_asc]
module.de-b2b-pprod-index.algolia_index.price_asc_replica: Refreshing state... [id=pprod_products_de_price_asc]
module.de-b2b-dev-index.algolia_index.index: Refreshing state... [id=dev_products_de]
module.de-b2b-pprod-index.algolia_index.index: Refreshing state... [id=pprod_products_de]
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
Error: Too many list items
  on ../products-index/main.tf line 10, in resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes":
  10: resource "algolia_index" "product_indexes" {
Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
time=2021-09-14T12:29:01Z level=error msg=1 error occurred:
    * exit status 1
```

It's unclear to me what is going wrong. How should I interpret that error message, and fix the error?

Also, would you say this is the best way to achieve my goal (declaring 4 resources that resemble each other with as little repetition as possible?)

Comment: Part of your question claims you are converting eight resources into a single resource with a `for_each` meta-argument, but later you state you expect to generate four declared resources. Should it be four or eight? Either way, it appears that the iterated Map structure is duplicating values (especially arithmetically considering the error message is thrown eight times despite length of four, and claims two declared instead of one).

Comment: I'm declaring 4 resources, but in a module that is used twice, which explains the 8 resources. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I added the calling file, it should help understanding what is going on here.

Comment: Ok if the module containing the resource is declared twice, then it is more likely that the provider has a validation check on one of the arguments in the block, and the value is failing the check. Unfortunately the provider's error message is not super transparent. Does this config also fail `validate` in addition to `plan`?

Comment: I'm a terraform n00b, so I've run terraform validate from the root of terraform, and it passes, but I'm not sure if that the correct thing to do or if I need to do in a specific path of the tree. Meanwhile, I'm exploring with modules of modules, it might be cleaner than a foreach.

Comment: Hilariously, I have now the exact same error message without `for_each`, with modules of modules 

Comment: Oooooh `ranking_config` appears twice!!!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

the error message is unhelpful in that it did not tell me that `ranking_config` was a duplicate. removing the duplicate block fixes the issue.